# rebasing DLLs for debug purpose, anyone doing it?

Tags: windows, debugging, dll

in an article about Windows debugging and the CrashFinder application, John Robbins says: "You should run REBASE.EXE as part of your build process to ensure that it is always done." (Bugslayer, Microsoft Systems Journal, April 1998, http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/bugslayer0498.aspx)

I would like to know if the rebasing for debug purpose is worth the trouble.

There is a similar question [Is rebasing DLLs (or providing an appropriate default load address) worth the trouble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969190/is-rebasing-dlls-or-providing-an-appropriate-default-load-address-worth-the-tro) but it is not related to debug purpose but to speeding up DLLs loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's still well worth rebasing your DLL so that it doesn't clash with other DLLs in the host process.  I won't list the benefits since you do so in the links in your question!

Comment: Clashing makes less of a difference in newer versions of Windows with ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization).  If your DLLs are enabled for ASLR, they're going to get relocated at load time even if their preferred address ranges don't overlap with those of other DLLs already loaded into the process's address space.  That's identical to the run-time cost of getting relocated because of a clash.