# Java Memory Management - java web start "Error: could not create the java virtual machine"

Tags: java, jvm

I have defined a jnlp file with `initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"` on a machine that has 16Gb with 12Gb available.  The JVM running is a 32-bit JVM because of native libraries.  I understand that I must have 1Gb of contiguous memory available to allocate that max.  If I reduce the `max-heap-size` to 768, then it runs as normal, and sometimes I don't need to reduce it.

Two questions:

1. Why is the machine checking max-heap-size initially before the JVM starts up?  Are there assertions that are being performed?
2. Why would I not be able to allocate the full 1Gb from the get go if I have 12Gb available - assuming that there is a contiguous 1Gb block available?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the 64-bit JVM...

If on Windows, using 32-bit JVM, you need to research "large address aware" (JVM compiled/linked with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE option). It will allow you to use larger memory footprint with 32-bit. You can set the bit on a particular executable.

[Drawbacks of using /LARGEADDRESSAWARE for 32 bit Windows executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288728/drawbacks-of-using-largeaddressaware-for-32-bit-windows-executables)

If on Linux, look at your system hard or soft limits. That may be limiting the max size of your process. Also, you may have process control groups.

For ulimits, on Linux/UNIX try

```
ulimit -a
```

Specifically look at ulimit -m or -v settings. If those are unlimited, you may be experiencing another type of control mechanism.

Comment: Client machines are Windows, and I am not sure what you mean by hard and soft limits?

Comment: It was a Linux answer, but applies to Windows. Your OS imposes a maximum process size. It is configurable. You need to look at "large address aware" setting for 32-bit JVM on windows.

Comment: You should be able to set a bit on the jvm executable to enable /LARGESPACEAWARE support. See my revision and the SO link.

Comment: This solves the memory issue, can you help with the answer the JNLP issue?  Is there an assert happening before the JVM boots up that check my max-heap-size against what the JVM would be able to allocate?

Comment: I would expect the JVM to allocate the full start-size heap at bootup and to assert the max heap size is legal.

Comment: why would the max heap size not be legal?  I have 12 Gb available and I am asking for 1Gb.  This meets all of the parameters that Oracle has put in place for a 32-bit JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Partial educated guess to:

> Why would I not be able to allocate the full 1Gb from the get go if I have 12Gb available - assuming that there is a contiguous 1Gb block available?

You wrote that JVM running is a 32-bit JVM because of native libraries. Note that then those native libraries are part of your process, and even if they don't allocate huge amounts of memory, they may nevertheless fragment the 2 GB virtual address space (which you're limited to, without LARGESPACEAWARE) so that you may not have a contiguous 1 GB block left. You might want to study the the native libraries' base addresses and [rebasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969190/is-rebasing-dlls-or-providing-an-appropriate-default-load-address-worth-the-tr). There's a free tool called [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx), which is great for studying these issues.