# How Rebase work with ASLR(Address space layout randomization)

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I am very confused. Rebase can adjust the address of DLL in the address space in a as I know, so the program don't need to relocate and won't lead to copy-on-write. It can improve the performance of program. But ASLR means the OS will load the ASLR random every times. So I think it is conflict that ASLR will relocate the DLL file ? Is that mean Rebase make no sense now? Or there are some tricks make ASLR and Rebase work together?
PS:I have read a lot of related article or question. Someone say  both of them can work together without detailed reason. Someone say no.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969190/is-rebasing-dlls-or-providing-an-appropriate-default-load-address-worth-the-tr/4871945#4871945](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969190/is-rebasing-dlls-or-providing-an-appropriate-default-load-address-worth-the-tr/4871945#4871945)

Comment: AFAIK ASLR indeed eliminates the need to use rebase at all.

Comment: @drescherjm I have read this  before  I post this question. It's not enough. I want to know  
 in detail how Rebase work with ASLR.

Comment: Rebases doesn't "work with" (I.e. coordinate actions with) ASLR. Rebasing comes first at build time. And then ASLR relocates the module at run time.